# how to sum hour/minutes from foreach

Tags: php, date, time, mariadb

How do I sum the times to return hours/minutes.
I need to sum IN with OUT.
Because people can come and start multiple times.

**Table Data**

```
|     Day    |   Hour   | Status |
|------------|----------|--------|
| 03/04/2021 | 19:45:05 | in     |
| 03/04/2021 | 20:03:50 | out    |
| 03/04/2021 | 20:04:34 | in     |
| 03/04/2021 | 20:04:51 | out    |
| 03/04/2021 | 21:04:59 | in     |
| 03/04/2021 | 23:59:59 | out    |
| 03/04/2021 | 22:08:07 | in     |
| 03/04/2021 | 22:08:55 | out    |
| 03/05/2021 | 14:46:32 | in     |
| 03/05/2021 | 19:25:09 | out    |
```

**Code**

```php
foreach ($timesheets as $timesheet) {
    $total -= strtotime($timesheet['hour']);
}
    
// Absolute value of time difference in seconds
$diff  = abs($total);
    
// Convert $diff to minutes
$tmins = $diff / 60;
    
// Get hours
$hours = floor($tmins / 60);
    
// Get minutes
$mins = $tmins%60;

return "<b>$hours</b> hours and<b>$mins</b> minutes</b>";
```

**Data Array**

```php
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 2021-03-05 [1] => 19:25:09 [2] => out )
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 2021-03-05 [1] => 14:46:32 [2] => in )
    [2] => Array ( [0] => 2021-03-04 [1] => 22:08:55 [2] => out ) 
    [3] => Array ( [0] => 2021-03-04 [1] => 22:08:07 [2] => in ) 
    [4] => Array ( [0] => 2021-03-04 [1] => 23:59:59 [2] => out ) 
    [5] => Array ( [0] => 2021-03-04 [1] => 21:04:59 [2] => in ) 
    [6] => Array ( [0] => 2021-03-04 [1] => 20:04:51 [2] => out )
    [7] => Array ( [0] => 2021-03-04 [1] => 20:04:34 [2] => in )
    [8] => Array ( [0] => 2021-03-04 [1] => 20:03:50 [2] => out ) 
    [9] => Array ( [0] => 2021-03-04 [1] => 19:42:05 [2] => in )
)
```

Comment: Please post data as text, not images.

Comment: Search engines and humans with disabilities will have a far easier time reading your question when you avoid posting images where text can be provided. Please [edit].

Comment: Is there a reason that the ordering is out of sequence?  EG: `in - 21:04:59` and `in - 22:08:07` with the nearest being `out - 22:08:55`. Is there an ID or other column that retains the ordering of the sequence that they can be grouped on?

Comment: ordered by id order desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `strtotime` converts to a unix-timestamp value, you would need to supply the full date and time to get an accurate account of the timestamps. However SQL can be used to do this for you instead - by using a pivot table and some built-in `DATETIME` functions.

### Pivot Table Query

First the dates need to be sorted appropriately by the date and time `in` with their corresponding date and time `out` ordering by the `ID` column as noted in your comment.

Then use `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.Day, ' ', t.Hour), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as Date_Time` to convert the individual `DATE` and `TIME` columns into a `DATETIME` value.

This will create a pivot table of separate `in` and `out` date-time values per row. Allowing the use of [`TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, ...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to retrieve the number of seconds between the two `DATETIME` values.

> It is important to note that `INNER JOIN` is used to exclude any date
> and time `in` that does not have a corresponding date and time `out`.

```sql
SELECT
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, in_time.Date_time, out_time.Date_Time) AS diff_sec,
   in_time.Date_time AS in_date_time,
   out_time.Date_Time AS out_date_time
FROM (
    SELECT
        ID,
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.Day, ' ', t.Hour), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS Date_Time
    FROM table_name AS t
    WHERE t.Status = 'in'
    ORDER BY ID ASC
) AS in_time
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ID,
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.Day, ' ', t.Hour), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS Date_Time
    FROM table_name AS t
    WHERE t.Status = 'out'
    ORDER BY ID ASC
) AS out_time
ON out_time.ID = (
    SELECT MIN(ID)
    FROM table_name AS t
    WHERE t.Status = 'out'
    AND t.ID > in_time.ID
)
```

### Pivot Table Result

```
| diff_sec | in_date_time        | out_date_time       |
| -------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1125     | 2021-03-04 19:45:05 | 2021-03-04 20:03:50 |
| 17       | 2021-03-04 20:04:34 | 2021-03-04 20:04:51 |
| 10500    | 2021-03-04 21:04:59 | 2021-03-04 23:59:59 |
| 48       | 2021-03-04 22:08:07 | 2021-03-04 22:08:55 |
| 16717    | 2021-03-05 14:46:32 | 2021-03-05 19:25:09 |
```

### Duration in Seconds Summation

In PHP you can retrieve the *Pivot Table Result* query using `array_sum()` and `array_column(..., 'diff_sec')` to get the summation of the duration in seconds.

Example: https://3v4l.org/Af7Cn

```php
$diff = array_sum(array_column($timesheets, 'diff_sec'));
$tmins = $diff / 60;
$hours = floor($tmins / 60);
$mins = $tmins%60;

echo "$hours hours and $mins minutes";
// 7 hours and 53 minutes
```

In SQL wrap `SUM()` around the resulting `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` query to retrieve the total number of seconds (`28407`) from all of the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` values.

```sql
SELECT
   SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, in_time.Date_time, out_time.Date_Time)) AS total_sec
FROM (
    SELECT
        ID,
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.Day, ' ', t.Hour), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS Date_Time
    FROM table_name AS t
    WHERE t.Status = 'in'
    ORDER BY ID ASC
) AS in_time
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ID,
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.Day, ' ', t.Hour), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS Date_Time
    FROM table_name AS t
    WHERE t.Status = 'out'
    ORDER BY ID ASC
) AS out_time
ON out_time.ID = (
    SELECT MIN(ID)
    FROM table_name AS t
    WHERE t.Status = 'out'
    AND t.ID > in_time.ID
)
```

### hh:mm:ss Duration

[`SEC_TO_TIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) can be used to display the duration in `hh:mm:ss` format for hours, minutes, and seconds (`07:53:27`) of the resulting total of seconds.

```sql
SELECT
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, in_time.Date_time, out_time.Date_Time))) AS duration
FROM (
   SELECT
      ID,
      STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.Day, ' ', t.Hour), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS Date_Time
   FROM table_name AS t
   WHERE t.Status = 'in'
   ORDER BY ID ASC
) AS in_time
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT
       ID,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.Day, ' ', t.Hour), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS Date_Time
   FROM table_name AS t
   WHERE t.Status = 'out'
   ORDER BY ID ASC
) AS out_time
ON out_time.ID = (
   SELECT MIN(ID)
   FROM table_name AS t
   WHERE t.Status = 'out'
   AND t.ID > in_time.ID
);
```

Example on [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eD3vALMEzAASCGjfLuRT8z/0)

### Formatting the Duration

[`TIME_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) can be used with your desired [`format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to refine the duration output.

```
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(...), '%H hours and %i minutes') AS duration_formatted
# 07 hours and 53 minutes
```

Alternatively in PHP use `explode(':', ...)` to parse the returned duration as desired.

Example https://3v4l.org/9miQT

```php
vprintf('%d hours and %d minutes', explode(':', $timesheet['duration'], 2));
// 7 hours and 53 minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks like it's in reverse order. You can either query your data in ascending order or use `array_reverse()`.

```
$timesheets = array_reverse($timesheets);
```

Then you can group `in` and `out` time together with `array_chunk()`.

```
$chunks = array_chunk($timesheets, 2);
```

Then you can calculate the difference between `in` and `out` time with `array_map()`.

```
$diffs = array_map(function ($chunk) {
    return strtotime($chunk[1][1]) - strtotime($chunk[0][1]);
}, $chunks);
```

And sum the time differences with `array_sum()`.

```
$sum = array_sum($diffs);
```

Then print out the time.

```
$seconds = $sum % 60;
$minutes = ($sum / 60) % 60;
$hours = (int) ($sum / 3600);

echo "$hours hours $minutes minutes $seconds seconds";
```